# I am trying to insert records into a an object list but nothing gets inserted when I call the method. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to insert data into a list using a method but nothing I attempt to insert shows up after I call the method. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm calling InsertMedicationOrder.

```
    private List<Medication> Meds;

    private List<MedOrder> MedOrder_;

    public FakeMedicationAccessor()
    {  
        MedOrder_ = new List<MedOrder>() 
        { 
            new MedOrder(){}
        };
    }

    public int InsertMedicationOrder(int orderID, int employeeID, int itemID, string itemName, int quantity)
    {
        MedOrder_.Add(GetMedicationOrder(orderID, employeeID, itemID, itemName, quantity));

        return 0;
    }

    public MedOrder GetMedicationOrder(int orderID, int employeeID, int itemID,string itemName, int quantity)
    {
        return new MedOrder
        {
            outgoingOrderID = orderID,
            employeeID = employeeID,
            itemID = itemID,
            itemName = itemName,
            quantityOrdered = quantity,
            itemCategoryID = "Medication"
        };
    }
```

The method is passed into here-

```
public bool CreateMedicationOrder(int orderID, int employeeID, int itemID, string itemName, int quantity)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        result = (1 == _activityAccessor.InsertMedicationOrder(orderID, employeeID, itemID, itemName, quantity));
    }
    catch (System.ApplicationException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Meds not ordered", ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And called here

```
public void OrderMedications() 
{
    _medicationManager = new MedicationManager();
    int orderID = 1;
    int employeeID = 66;
    int itemID = 1;
    string itemName = "Med_A";

    _medicationManager.CreateMedicationOrder(orderID, employeeID, itemID, itemName, Int32.Parse(Quantity_input.Text));
}
```

Instantiation of FakeMedicationAccessor

```
  private IMedicationAccessor _activityAccessor;


    public MedicationManager()
    {
        _activityAccessor = new FakeMedicationAccessor();

    }

    public MedicationManager(IMedicationAccessor MedicationManager)
    {
        _activityAccessor = MedicationManager;

    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code that calls these methods?

Comment: Is _activityAccessor of type FakeMedicationAccessor? Can u show where you are initializing _activityAccessor ? In FakeMedicationAccessor constructor, you always reset the MedOrder_list.

Comment: Yes. I added it to my code. And can you clarify what you mean by reset the MedOrder_list?

Comment: @Daulton, In OrderMedications() you created a fresh object of MedicationManager, which internally creates a fresh object _activityAccessor of type FakeMedicationAccessor. Now your _activityAccessor contains the list MedOrder_ with only one blank MedOrder. At the end of OrderMedications() method your MedOrder_  list will have one more MedOrder. Now if you use one more MedicationManager instance to display the list or something similar purpose, your MedOrder_ will have only one blank MedOrder object because of  MedicationManager constructor and FakeMedicationAccessor constructor.

Comment: Please  review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. It is very unclear how all this pieces fit together and how you check the resulting list... The fact you comparing `1==0` as shown in Alb's answer does not help with understanding of posted code.

Comment: Try *private List<MedOrder> MedOrder_ = new List<MedOrder>();*

Comment: @Daulton I have a ***how to continue* proposal** in my answer. You have to understand that I also flagged this question for closing because the description **as-is** isn't valid to reproduce the problem: You mention calling `InsertMedicationOrder` and blaming `List.Add()` doesn't work while no code provided to prove your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You returns **0** from `InsertMedicationOrder` and you compare it with 1

```
1 == _activityAccessor.InsertMedicationOrder(orderID, employeeID, itemID, itemName, quantity));
```

`1 == 0` will always be false.

Return 1 or

```
var before = MedOrder_.Count
MedOrder_.Add(...);
return MedOrder_.Count - before;
```

to check if an element is added to your list.

**Edit:**

Here is what happens in your code

- Whenever you call `InsertMedication()`, an element is added to your
  list. This is a fact.
- Whenever you call `CreateMedicationOrder()`, it returns false, but **your
  list has grown**. This is a fact.
- You could check it after the line `_medicationManager.CreateMedicationOrder()` and will see by yourself, like:

  `var currentSize = _medicationManager.MedOrder_.Count;`
  which wouldn't compile, because `MedOrder_` is **private** which is a good practice if you don't just keep calling `OrderMedications()` because:
- Whenever you call `OrderMedications()`, this list is gone because of you
  tell `_medicationManager` to point to a completely new object by the code:

  `_medicationManager = new MedicationManager();`

So assuming you are not doing this completely crazy thing to call `OrderMedications()` **you indeed have a lot of items in your list!** (by calling `InsertMedication()` multiple times) BUT I don't see any code, that checks that list for emptyness or for elements within or even code to check the count. So I propose **you should look at the list to see what it contains** For example, use foreach. Create a new function inside *FakeMedicationAccessor* class:

```
void ReadMedicationOrders()
{
    foreach(var item in MedOrder_)
        Console.WriteLine(item.itemName);  //if it is a console application
}
```

**In case**

you do only calling `OrderMedications()` (let say from you *Main*), then you need to initialize `_medicationManager` only once in your other class. So write this to the top of your class:

```
MedicationManager _medicationManager = new MedicationManager();
```

and get rid of re-initialization within your function. Delete the line I commented out:

```
public void OrderMedications() 
{
    //_medicationManager = new MedicationManager();
    int orderID = 1;
    int employeeID = 66;
    int itemID = 1;
    string itemName = "Med_A";

    _medicationManager.CreateMedicationOrder(orderID, employeeID, itemID, itemName, Int32.Parse(Quantity_input.Text));
}
```

You may also need to change `MedOrder_` inside *FakeMedicationAccessor* class to internal or public, or create a new function (inside *FakeMedicationAccessor*), like:

```
void PrintMedicationOrders()
{
    //do your logic here similar to ReadMedicationOrders()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with a singleton instance of the MedicationManager class. Each time you are creating an object of MedicationManager classs which will in turn create a new instance of FakeMedicationAccessor class.

```
    public void OrderMedications() 
    {
        if(_medicationManager == null)
        {
            _medicationManager = new MedicationManager();
        }
        int orderID = 1;
        int employeeID = 66;
        int itemID = 1;
        string itemName = "Med_A";

        _medicationManager.CreateMedicationOrder(orderID, employeeID, itemID, itemName, Int32.Parse(Quantity_input.Text));
    }
```

Do that null check whereever you create a new instance of MedicationManager